# height (min-height) 100% not working when content overflow?

Tags: html, css

I am building a 3 columns layout website. The `header` will fixed on the top and `nav` will fixed on the left. Then the wrapper will contain `main` and `aside`. What I want is main and aside can fill the wrapper's height.

And here is my css. You can also see my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/scarletsky/h8r2z/3/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    background: red;
}

.nav {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

.main {
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
}

.aside {
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}

.u-color-white {
    color: white;
}
```

It seems that they can work well. But when the content's height in `main` or `aside` more than  their own height, it will not work. I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone help me?
Thx!

Comment: @codedude But I don't like his solution... I think there may be a more elegant solution

Comment: Agreed. Removed my possible duplicate comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a very strict layout. everything is fixed..
what if you need to change the header from 100px height to 120? you'll have to change it accordingly in a lot of different places.

**This is a pure CSS solution for your layout, without fixing any height or width. (you can fix the height or width if you want to)
This layout is totally responsive, and cross browser.**

if you don't fix the height/width of the elements, they will span exactly what they need.

Here's a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/PSaTG/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<header class="Header"></header>
<div class="HeightTaker">
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <nav class="Nav"></nav>
        <div class="ContentArea">
            <div class="Table">
                <div class="Main"></div>
                <div class="Aside"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body:before {
    content:'';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.Header {
    height: 100px;
    /*No need to fix it*/
    background-color: red;
}
.HeightTaker {
    position: relative;
}
.HeightTaker:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.Wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.Nav {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
.ContentArea {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.Table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Main {
    width: 70%;
    /*No need to fix it*/
    background-color: black;
    display: table-cell;
}
.Aside {
    width: 30%;
    /*No need to fix it*/
    background-color: black;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
.u-color-white {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: In fact I am using SASS, most things are variables :-)

Comment: It seems that you are using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to fix my problem?

Comment: Oh.. SASS is fine.  Indeed the equal height solution is by using the CSS table layout.

Comment: one more question. I've tried to remove the pseudo-element, but it seems that the pseudo-element is necessary. So, What is the effect of pseudo-element in your answer?

Comment: the trick that I'm using to span the rest of the container height, is to create an empty element (`body:before`) with float left that span the entire body height, and another empty element(`.HeightTaker:after`) with clear. now, the second empty element can't be in the same line with the floated one, so he's pushed down until he reaches the end of the floated element. witch is exactly 100% height. enlarging the `HeightTaker` with him..

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem. I'd recommend either having a background image for wrapper that makes it appear like aside has a min-height of 100% or using the method on this site:
http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: This is a really great resource. Thanks :-)

Comment: Accepting the answer or at least up voting it would be appreciated. :D

Comment: vote up, I like @avrahamcool 's answer, and accept it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

just see this fiddle.... hope this is what you want...

```
.aside {
width: 30%;
min-height: 100%;
position:fixed;
right: 0;
background: blue;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/h8r2z/6/

Comment: Before I ask this question, I know `position: fixed` will work. But this is not what I want. Because `aside` should not fixed..Thank you anyway!